# Filter renderer column data

Tags: magento2, grid, filter, multi-source-inventory

I've one grid similar to product grid.

```
<?php
namespace LazyCoder\WarehouseListing\Block\Adminhtml\Grid;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Backend\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory as DemoCollection;
use Magento\InventoryApi\Api\GetSourceItemsBySkuInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;

// also you can use Magento Default CollectionFactory
class Grid extends Extended
{
    protected $registry;
    protected $_objectManager = null;
    protected $demoFactory;
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Data $backendHelper,
        Registry $registry,
        ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        DemoCollection $demoFactory,
         \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
         GetSourceItemsBySkuInterface $sourceItemsBySku,
         ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepo,
         \Magento\Backend\Model\Session $session,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->demoFactory = $demoFactory;
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->getSourceItemsBySku = $sourceItemsBySku;
        $this->productRepository  = $productRepo;
        $this->session = $session;
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    }
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('index');
        $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {

        $demo = $this->demoFactory->create()
            ->addFieldToSelect('*');
        $demo->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('neq' => ''));

        $this->setCollection($demo);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn(
            'entity_id',
            [
                'header_css_class' => 'a-center',
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'name' => 'entity_id',
                'align' => 'center',
                'index' => 'entity_id',
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'entity_id',
            [
                'header' => __('ID'),
                'type' => 'number',
                'index' => 'entity_id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id',
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'name',
            [
                'header' => __('Name'),
                'type' => 'text',
                'index' => 'name',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id',
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'sku',
            [
                'header' => __('SKU'),
                'index' => 'sku',
                'class' => '',
                'width' => '125px',
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'color',
            [
                'header' => __('Color'),
                'index' => 'color',
                'class' => '',
                'width' => '125px',
                'renderer'  => 'LazyCoder\WarehouseListing\Block\Adminhtml\Listing\Edit\Tab\Renderer\Color','filter_condition_callback' => [$this, '_filterCollectionByColor'],
            ]
        );

       $this->addColumn('size', 
    [
        'header' => __('Size'),
        'index' => 'size',
        'renderer'  =>'LazyCoder\WarehouseListing\Block\Adminhtml\Listing\Edit\Tab\Renderer\Size','filter_condition_callback' => [$this, '_filterCollection'],
    ]);


       $this->addColumn(
            'warehouse',
            [
                'header' => __('Warehouse'),
                'index' => 'warehouse',
                'class' => '',
                'width' => '125px',
                'renderer'  => 'LazyCoder\WarehouseListing\Block\Adminhtml\Listing\Edit\Tab\Renderer\Warehouse','filter_condition_callback' => [$this, '_filterCollectionByWarehouse'],
            ]
        );

       return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/index', ['_current' => true]);
    }


    protected function _filterCollection($collection, $column)
    {

        $value = trim($column->getFilter()->getValue());

        $_product = $this->productFactory->create();
        $isAttributeExist = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('size');
        $optionId = '';
        if ($isAttributeExist && $isAttributeExist->usesSource()) {
            $optionId = $isAttributeExist->getSource()->getOptionId($value);
        }

        $this->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('size', array('eq' => $optionId));


        return $this;
    }

    protected function _filterCollectionByColor($collection, $column)
    {

        $value = trim($column->getFilter()->getValue());

        $_product = $this->productFactory->create();
        $isAttributeExist = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('color');
        $optionId = '';
        if ($isAttributeExist && $isAttributeExist->usesSource()) {
            $optionId = $isAttributeExist->getSource()->getOptionId($value);
        }

        $this->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('color', array('eq' => $optionId));


        return $this;
    }

    protected function _filterCollectionByWarehouse($collection, $column)
    {

        $value = trim($column->getFilter()->getValue());

        //$this->session->setMyValue($value);

        $select = $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                ['isi' => 'inventory_source_item'],
                'e.sku = isi.sku',
                ['source_code' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`isi`.source_code)'),]
            )->where('isi.source_code = ?', $value)->group('e.sku'); 

        return $this;
    }

}
```

I can able to filter all other columns expect warehouse column.
   Here's how I get warehouse column value. I used renderer.

```
$sourceItems = $this->getSourceItemsBySku->execute($row->getSku());


        foreach($sourceItems as $sourceItem){
            $value[] = $sourceItem->getSourceCode().':'.$sourceItem->getQuantity();
        }


        if(empty($value)){
            return '';
        }else{
            return implode('<br>', $value);
        }
```

If you check below image, I took one SKU as an example, I've joined 2 tables data to get warehouse values.

**Note : I've used default multi source inventory here term warehouse means source.**

If I enter china to warehouse column and hit enter then it worked as I expected but after filter cant able to navigate to other pages. Take a look at below.

https://streamable.com/u1yom

In join main table is `catalog_product_entity` and joined with `inventory_source_item`. Take look at below.

[image]
[image]

If you can see other table having warehouse information, but its duplicated raw per sku, Like if SKU has one more  warehouse assigned then it there'll be 4 entries in `inventory_source_item` table.

Does any one have idea what's wrong here ? I'm sure there's very small mistake but cant get that. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove ->group('e.sku') or use ->group('e.entity_id') and check. Might your issue will fix.

Comment: I did try same thing but same output no pagination after filter.